# programmatically creating links in Zip file - java

Tags: java, zip

I am creating a zip file using [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). There will also be a manifest file (a csv file) which will have links to the entries in the Zip file. How do I programmatically create links for the zip entries ?

Comment: You create links into the unzipped input to the zipped file. Offsets into a zipped file are useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep track of all the entries while you write them, you should be able to add another entry containing the "links" (but how should a csv link to a file? Please specify what you try to achieve).

If you intend to use the file under windows, you could create `.lnk` files programmatically; but this only works for one file per link. On unices, ZipOutputStream cannot create symlinks, but [ZipFileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) can.